# How to pick files from my device?

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

I am doing career form, in this form have resume upload concept. I searched how to browse file form ios device but i am not getting any solution so please some one can help to solve this problem. I am new in ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot browse any files on iOS device.

You have to update your app to say what type of files it can edit/read.

Then another app would have to share that file. When that source app shares a file type tht your app accept, it would listed as a destination the user can select.

Comment: we cannot browse directly?

Comment: ,please tell me what is that app.

Comment: Iam not accepted this answer.

Comment: It is possible in iOs.

Answer (score 0):

Asper my knowledge because of the security reasons we can't access all files. You can access albums,images,contacts ... but not documents. I think try to load the png files of the resume in Photos and try to access it.

Comment: pdf file picking is not possible in ios?

Comment: Any alternative is there for this process?

Comment: first you have to store those pdf files in your server and get those files from server & display it in a view

Comment: iam asking end user uploading concept?

Comment: There is no way of getting the doc files

Comment: By configuring another app ,it is possible?

Comment: You can do using the another app but even then also you should load those file in the other app